# Whats the point of transactional non xa JMS Sessions?

Tags: java, jms

Is it just me or is the JMS API inconsistent with regards to how it models Transacted and XA Transacted equivalents ?

I dont fully appreciate why there are XA forms for ConnectionFactory, QueueConnectionFactory, Session and so on and so much duplication:

For example

```
XAQueueConnection

    XAQueueSession
    createXAQueueSession() throws JMSException;

    QueueSession
    createQueueSession(boolean transacted,
                       int acknowledgeMode) throws JMSException;
```

contains methods for a non transacted and transacted session ?

- Why both ?
- If i have a XAQC why would i want a non transacted QS ?
- If i wanted that why would i create a XAQueueConnection ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These provide a gradient of classes of service.  JMS allows for...

- Messages outside of a unit of work
- Messages inside of a single-phase commit (1PC)
- Messages inside of a two-phase commit (2PC / XA)

The cost of each of these increases with the degree of reliability.  Generally, you want to use the least-cost method that the application requires.  If you have a non-persistent, expiring, fire-and-forget message (for example, a stock ticker event) putting it inside a unit of work is wasteful.  Similarly, if you need a transacted session but JMS is your only resource manager, XA would be a waste.

On the other hand, if you do need XA for some operations, that does not mean that you should then use XA for all operations.  For example, you may have a single connection within which you maintain one session for XA transactions and another session for non-XA messaging.  The first of these is receiving requests for long-running processes and updating a database with the process details.  The other session is used to send periodic status updates.  The connection must be an XAConnection but for performance purposes you need both an XA and a non-XA session underneath it.  You could also maintain separate connections but this method allows you to perform both XA and non-XA messaging within a single connection.  For brokers with many connections, this optimization can be critical.

Admittedly this is not a very common use case, but it it is still a valid case and useful enough to have been included in the specification.